# Spring MVC: Render page from ModelAndView in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc, jsp, model-view-controller

I am building a project using Spring MVC. I want to transfer a JSON object from my current page to the next page. What I have done is created a controller, to which I am sending the object via POST AJAX call. The controller then creates a ModelAndView object for the next page stored as a jsp, adds the object as one of the attributes of said ModelAndView, and returns it. Now I need to redirect to the page returned as the ModelAndView. Here is the relevant code:

Controller:

```
public ModelAndView nextPageController(@RequestBody String passedJsonString) {
    ModelAndView nextPage = new ModelAndView("/nextPage.jsp");
    nextPage.addObject("passedJsonString", passedJsonString);
    return nextPage;
}
```

AJAX Call:

```
            controllerUrl = "/controller/path";
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                headers : {
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                url : controllerUrl,
                data : JSON.stringify(jsonDataToBePassed),
                success : function(dataString) {
                    console.log(dataString);
                }
            });
```

The AJAX call is executed successfully and the ModelAndView object is returned as expected. Now I need to render the next page with the attributes added in the controller intact. I realize that what I am doing may be wrong, and there may be a better way to achieve this, so any guidance on how to do this may be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you make an ajax call to controller it expects some result and based on that you can proceed.

In your case the response has been returned to ajax function after successful completion from controller.

If you want to send to another page then write a method in controller and return the page(/nextPage.jsp) in that controller method.

SO below in your code.

```
success : function(dataString) {
      window.location.href = "/path/of/controllerMethod"; //redirect to controller method which returns the jsp page
}
```

and create the method like below :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/path/of/controllerMethod")
public ModelAndView returnJspPageControllerMethod() {
    ModelAndView nextPage = new ModelAndView("/nextPage.jsp");
    return nextPage;
}
```